# What's wrong with this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I am getting a syntax error for my MySQL (5.5.24) query.

The error is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''topics'( 'topicid' int unsigned not null auto_increment primary
>   key, 'creator' at line 1

The query is:

```
create table 'topics'(
  'topicid' int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  'creator' varchar(255) not null,
  'createtime' datetime not null,
  'content' text not null
);
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes.  Use ` instead of '

```
CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `topicid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `creator` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `createtime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I also would recommend specifying the engine.

Answer (score 2):

The error is the single quotes around the table and column names.  If you want to escape these names use back ticks (`) not quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using quotes? Try

```
CREATE TABLE topics (
  topicid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

  creator varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  createtime datetime NOT NULL,

  content text NOT NULL
);
```